# Where to put grand central dispatch code?

Tags: xcode, swift4

I have set up some code that looks like this

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue.1", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
queue.async {
   AppUtility().run(X: self.BitCount)      
}
```

Here is the function that is called:

```
public func run(X: UILabel) {
    var placeHolder = 0
    while  placeHolder == 0{
        if globalValues.bitsPerSecond != 0 {
            globalValues.Bits = globalValues.Bits + 1
                //globalValues.bitsPerSecond
            print("Ran")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(globalValues.Bits, forKey: "bits")
        X.text = "\(globalValues.Bits)"
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

This code will update a label everysecond through a counter while the user is looking at the screen. From what I have read I believe my code to be correct however I have no Idea where to put it so it can always run in the background. Any help?

Comment: What does `run(X:)` do? Share it's implementation.

Comment: And... when you say "_run in background_", what's the scenario you're looking at?

Comment: I want the code to always be running when the user is on the given view that the view controller runs. I have updated the description to include the function being called.

Comment: Why don't you do this in `viewDidLoad()` of the `UIViewController` that defines the `BitCount` label?

Comment: Besides, your `run(X:)` has a really weird implementation. That `while`, that `if` and the fact that it doesn't update `globalValues.Bits`.

Comment: Also, any UI updation should occur on main thread. i.e. `X.text = "\(globalValues.Bits)"` should be dispatched to main thread.

Comment: I already tried putting it in the view did road but it doesn’t seem to run also I update the label in the secondary thread as I don’t have the whole program on a loop

Comment: Is this iOS or MacOS?

Comment: This project is for iOS

Comment: What? "_whole program on a loop_"!? Why would you even... what? ...anyways, I got ur code working by putting that in `viewDidLoad()` and updating `globalValues.Bits` just before updating `X` (on main thread). I dunno but it just looks like a timer to me. Need to handle the retain cycles though. Why don't you just describe your problem and ask for alternative solutions instead?

Answer (score 0):

> I have no Idea where to put it so it can always run in the background

In iOS, code *doesn't* run in the background. When your app is backgrounded, it is *suspended*.

If the idea is that the label should have the right value when the app comes back into the foreground, *as if* the counting had gone on while in the background, then just use the activation event as a signal to calculate how long we were backgrounded and adjust the label value accordingly.

Comment: By the way, calling `sleep` is wrong, and so your entire code is incorrect. Basically you probably just want a repeating Timer here. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer